# AWS DynamoDB Scan | Scan if array of keys exists in a map

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store user info. 
Every user has a map with hobbies as key and some text as value, example:

```
{'fishing': 'Its fun!', 'running': 'Its healthy!'}
```

Now, I want to scan my table for users with specific hobbies:

```
['dancing', 'fishing', 'cooking']
```

**Question:** Is it possible to `scan` a DynamoDB table to check if keys in a map exists?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152826/dynamodb-scan-items-where-map-contains-a-key

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to scan a DynamoDB table to check if keys in a map exists.

Let's say your entry in the dynamoDB looks something like this:

```
{
   "userId" : 123,
   "hobbyMap" : {
      "fishing" : "Its fun!",
      "running" : "Its healthy!"
   }
}
```

The Filter Expression you can write is:

```
FilterExpression : "attribute_exists(hobbyMap.dancing) OR attribute_exists(hobbyMap.fishing) OR attribute_exists(hobbyMap.cooking)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If hobbies attribute would be a StringSet then you could do a scan like this:

```
    {
        "TableName": "tbl_name",
        "FilterExpression": "( contains(hobbies, :hobby1) ) OR ( contains(hobbies, :hobby2) )  )",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":hobby1": {
                "S": "dancing"
            },
            ":hobby2": {
                "S": "fishing"
            },

        }
    }
```